# Rendering a form based on bean field value

Tags: forms, jsf, render

I want to ask user to input password before submitting a file. So `<h:panelGroup>` should be rendered after hit the Submit button. But, `<h:panelGoup>` never be rendered.

test.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <t:inputFileUpload id="uploadedFile" storage="file"
                               value="#{UpdateBean.uploadedFile}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{UpdateBean.submit()}"/>
        </table>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup id="checkPassword" rendered="#{UpdateBean.submitIsPerformed}">
        <h:outputText id="message" value="${UpdateBean.message}" />
        <h:inputText id="password" value="#{UpdateBean.password}" />
        <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{UpdateBean.submitPassword()}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
```

UpdateBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "UpdateBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UpdateBean {
    protected boolean submitIsPerformed = false;
    protected String password = "";
    protected String message = "Input your password ";

    // omit getter and setter

    public void submit() {
        this.setSubmitIsPerformed(true);
        System.out.println(submitIsPerformed); // output is true

        while(true) {
           if(password.equals("123")) {
               break;
           }
       }

       // then process uploadedFile
    }

    public void submitPassword(){
       if(password.equals("123")) {
          message = "Password confirmed !";
       } else {
          message = "Password is wrong !";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `this.setSubmitIsPerformed(true);` defined?

Comment: @ryanyuyu it is setter for submitIsPerformed.

Comment: @Tiny you mean <h:commandButton><f:ajax id="checkPassword"></h:commandButton>?  I tried this, but does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the `submit()` method:

```
while(true) {
   if(password.equals("123")) {
       break;
   }
}
```

The `while(true)` prevents the action method from returning. As long as the action method doesn't return, the server won't return the HTTP response with the updated view. Effectively, one of your server's CPU is stuck into 100% and the client is infinitely waiting for HTTP response. You should have noticed it by checking the browser's progress indicator, if it has one.

You should basically immediately return after toggling the boolean:

```
public void submit() {
    submitIsPerformed = true;
}
```

And perform the password checking and upload file saving in `submitPassword()` method. However, as this isn't in the same form, the uploaded file will get lost. Even if you put it in the same form, it would be uploaded twice. But that's a different problem. I suggest to do the job the other way round.

Comment: Thank you! You solution did work. I also figured out the uploadFile.

Comment: Thanks again !     I have a question about your comment "As long as the action method doesn't return, the server won't return the HTTP response with the updated view." In one scenario, I want to upload a file and then persist the data to database. If any data is new, I want to prompt a window to ask user to decide whether persist the data or not. So using a form cannot solve this issue? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Just render a prompt window with another form? Are you ex-desktop developer? You might want to clear out your mindset as to client-server separation before diving into webdev :) For (JSF) web dev starters it's the easist to realize that JSF is merely a HTML code generator and that you need to be familiar with basic HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the suggestion from @BalusC, this is my updated code.

test.xhtml

```
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form>
                        <h:commandButton value="Upload a file" action="#{UpdateBean.submit()}">
                            <f:ajax render=":checkPassword" />
                        </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="checkPassword" styleClass="toggle" rendered="#{UpdateBean.submitIsPerformed}">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="Password" /></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="password" value="#{UpdateBean.password}" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{UpdateBean.submitPassword()}">
                        <f:ajax execute="password" render=":uploadFile" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                styleClass="toggle" rendered="#{UpdateBean.uploadFileIsPerformed}">

            <t:inputFileUpload id="uploadedFile" storage="file"
                               value="#{UpdateBean.uploadedFile}">
            </t:inputFileUpload>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{UpdateBean.uploadFile()}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

UploadBean.java

```
   public String submit() {

        setSubmitIsPerformed(true);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public String submitPassword(){
        if(password.equals("123"){
            setUploadFileIsPerformed(true);
            setSubmitIsPerformed(false);
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public String uploadFile(){
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```